# Apple shape with no gravity

Tags: classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, everyday-life

Would the shape of an apple change if it grew with no gravity?

I would expect it having a slightly narrower and deeper dent where the stem is attached but I cannot quite figure out how to estimate the order of magnitude of this effect.

I would try to estimate how much gravity deforms the apple during its growth. The roughest thing could be taking the ratio between binding energy between molecules and gravitational force on the molecules themselves.

Any other idea of how to model this?
Maybe the internal stress of the apple plays a role, or maybe there is some energy or strength scale related to the microscopic growth of the fruit.

Comment: With no gravity things tend to form spherical-like shapes (or disks if there's rotation). The apple seems already pretty spherical to me.

Comment: The shape may depend on the apple. I would guess the primary driving force would the evolutionary drive to spread it's seeds, i.e., reproduction. Designed to  eaten by animals which will their seeds?  It would be interesting to grow an apple tree on the space station in a microgravity environment.

Comment: An apple or a tree are built by living organisms, who react to gravity, so things gets messy.  I will say that in this example, the apple will grow the same; small apples just after the flower are upside down or at random orientation, but they grow round anyway. We can try to fully grow an apple upside down, see what shape it takes.  I say that it will have only the stem a little weaker.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while it would be an interesting experiment (could we put an apple tree on the ISS?) it's about the physiology of apples not physics.

Comment: Mmm @JohnRennie I do not agree. I think it could be possible to give a mathematical description of the process without getting too much into the biological specifics. I wrote the question hoping for such an answer, I am sorry if I stirred the curiosity an inappropriate way. If you feel like suggesting any editing to make the question more formal/technical please feel free to do so. I will try to do it myself. Thanks for the feedback anyways